# Does the Precision-Recall AUC approach the ROC AUC as the data becomes balanced?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, precision-recall

I am working on a Machine Learning classifier. It is a binary response and most predictor variables are categorical. I have several years of data and for some years, the response is imbalanced (more 1s than 0s) and for more recent years is gradually becomes balanced (roughly the same number of 1s and 0s). I am calculating/plotting both ROC AUC and Precision-Recall AUC. Would you expect that the Precision-Recall AUC approaches the ROC AUC as the data becomes balanced?

Because that's not really what I'm seeing. I'm still seeing a difference between the Precision-Recall AUC and the ROC AUC as the data becomes balanced. Since the positive case is what I am interested in, is the ROC AUC necessary at all?

Comment: If you’re just interested in predicting the positive cases, why do any machine learning at all instead of always predicting the result to be a positive one? (This is probably ridiculous, but your response will be insightful.)

Comment: @Dave budget...

Comment: So then you’re not just interested i catching the positive cases, right?

Comment: I'm interested in accurately predicting the positive cases, as accurately as possible, as this will lead to business decision. Accurately predicting negative cases will result in nothing (no actions taken on those negative cases). To blanket everyone as positive, is outside of our budgetary capabilities.

Comment: In other words, you need to accurately predict negative cases, too, in order to keep your business from pursuing negative cases, right?

Comment: what is the point that you are trying to make?

Comment: Most discussions revolving around class imbalance have at their root either a misunderstanding about what machine learning models do or what what problem they are trying to solve; in the extreme, I have addressed multiple questions on here and [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) that ask how to catch every instance of a category, to which the only response to to label every subject that category, no matter the features.

Comment: While I will not pretend to be addressing your explicit question about ROC and PR curves (to which I confess not knowing the answer), it is important to figure out and answer the questions someone should have had instead of just answering the questions someone happened to ask. If you know of [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), this notion is related. While I am curious about your explicit question, I wonder if it actually matters to your work or much of any work. (From what you’ve described, I think the answer does not matter to your work.)

Comment: What makes you think that True Positive Rate = Precision and False positive rate = Recall?

Comment: @Calimo that's what I'm thinking too (as I thought about this more).